# Python 3, passing dictionary values in a function to another function

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I'm making a simple dice game using PYTHON 3

1. I want the game to ask for how many players are going to play and for each player got their own name from the user input.
2. I want the game to ask every player if they want to roll the dice or not.

For now, I'm stuck where I want to get the values from the dictionary `player_dict` in the `main` function to the `roll_dice` function. So, I can print out the values which are the players name in the formatted string.

Thanks in advance, also sorry for bad english

```
from random import randint


def main():
    player = int(input('How many players> '))
    step = 1
    player += 1
    player_dict = {}


    for pl in range(1, player, step):
        player_name = input(f'Player {str(pl)} name> ')
        player_dict[pl] = player_name

    for x in player_dict:
        roll_dice()


def roll_dice():
    start_rolling = input(f'{} roll dice? y/n> ') # I want to assign player_dict values in the formatted string
    if start_rolling == 'y' or start_rolling == 'Y':
        roll = randint(1, 6)
        print(roll)
    return roll_dice



main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to pass the argument to your other function and nest everything under a for loop,  have a look. also there is room for improvement on the y/n option. But so far, seems great.

keep it up

from random import randint

```
def main():
    player = int(input('How many players> '))
    step = 1
    player += 1
    player_dict = {}


    for pl in range(1, player, step):
        player_name = input(f'Player {str(pl)} name> ')
        player_dict[pl] = player_name

    roll_dice(player_dict)


def roll_dice(players):
    for i in range(1,len(players)+1):
        start_rolling = input(f'{players[i]} roll dice? y/n> ') # I want to assign player_dict values in the formatted string
        if start_rolling == 'y' or start_rolling == 'Y':
            roll = randint(1, 6)
            print(roll)
    return roll_dice
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the values of `player_dict` inside the `roll_dice` function, you can pass the variable as a parameter. Or even pass only the value you want to print.

Just like this example:

```py
from random import randint


def main():
    player = int(input('How many players> '))
    step = 1
    player += 1
    player_dict = {}


    for pl in range(1, player, step):
        player_name = input(f'Player {str(pl)} name> ')
        player_dict[pl] = player_name

    for x in player_dict:
        roll_dice(player_dict[x])


def roll_dice(player_name):
    start_rolling = input(f'{player_name} roll dice? y/n> ') # I want to assign player_dict values in the formatted string
    if start_rolling == 'y' or start_rolling == 'Y':
        roll = randint(1, 6)
        print(roll)
    return roll_dice



main()
```